# How do I get data sensor data from Microsoft band 2 to a Raspberry pi without SDK? (To a programming language)

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi3, microsoft-band

How can I get sensor data from the Microsoft Band 2 to a Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian Jessie)? The data should be  available in a higher level programming language such as Python, Java or similar.

I want to be able to run a program (Java, Python or similar) that  automatically receive data for processing when the Band is in range.

It is ok to pair the MS Band with a supported phone (and app) first in order to get past the setup on the Band. It is also ok to run some command-line tools on the Raspberry in order to pair the devices the first time (keys etc).

I have managed to pair and connect to the device using command-line tool: 
sudo bluetoothctl -a

But I can't create any connection from Python using BluePy or following Tony DiCola's tutorial:
https://learn.adafruit.com/bluefruit-le-python-library/installation

My guess is that the Bluetooth LE privacy is messing things up?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the documentation which for some reason is all jammed into a PDF [here](https://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf).

It appears at the moment the only supported ways to get data of the band is using the SDK which only has support for iOS, Windoze and Andriod.

Comment: I understand that this is the supported way. But there are others reporting that they have connected via Bluetooth LE (not using SDK) and managed to access data. I have tried via BluePy but without success and also followed an Adafruit tutorial without success. This makes me believe I'm missing something (guessing the BLE privacy messing it up). I can't make a connection to the device using a programming environment but I can pair and make a connection via bluetoothctl -a.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to achieve a similar result (direct connection via BLE without SDK on Windows/other OS) but even if I managed to connect to the band "manually" it is impossible for me to understand the GATT profiles to read the data from sensors. I can't find any (unofficial) documentation on the web to read data directly.